# What difference between app-inf and web-inf folders in JavaEE applications?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-inf

Can you give me understanding of main difference between APP-INF and WEB-INF folders in javaEE applications.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/configurewebapp.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**APP-INF**

In an enterprise application (EAR application) which contains many war and jars (eg.WebApp1.war, WebApp2.war, EJB1.jar and EJB2.jar.) and suppose all these Modules want to use some classes which is available as part of a Jar (common.jar). So in this case it is better to Place this jar file inside under “APP-INF” directory,that why we don't need to put the same Jar 4 times inside each and every Modules.

**WEB-INF**

WEB-INF is a directory that is a private area of the web application, any files under WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly from browser by specifying the URL.

See EAR application structure;

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and one more question, is there any difference between lib and classes in APP-INF and in WEB-INF? i mean it's only logical difference or no difference here?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi WEB-INF represents one war, APP-INF represents more than one wars or jars. So lib and classes form both be different.APP-INF is aimed for common usages.

Comment: In another words application can see all jar if it placed in APP-INF and jars in WEB-INF can be see only in this WAR, i'm right?

Comment: Do note that this answer is correct only for WebLogic. APP-INF is a WebLogic proprietary feature. OP mentioned "JavaEE" applications.

Comment: -1, as this is a WebLogic-specific feature, rather than JavaEE.

Answer (score 21):

> Can you give me understanding of main difference between APP-INF and WEB-INF folders in java EE applications.

APP-INF is specific for WebLogic. In the Java EE standard it does not exist, hence for Java EE applications there is nothing to compare. Java EE does have an [EAR]/lib directory that takes the place of the non-standard APP-INF/lib. Optionally another directory can be configured in [EAR]/META-INF/application.xml"

```
<application>
   <library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

There is no direct replacement for APP-INF/classes in standard Java EE. You'll have to jar these up as well and put them in [EAR]/lib as well.