# Exclude properties file from a WAR type sub-module in Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin, maven-module

I have a complex scenario of packaging my EAR projects, below is the sort of visual description to fully understand it:

```
ProjA.ear
 |-- ProjA.war
 |-- Util.war
 |   |-- WEB-INF
 |   |   |-- classes
 |   |   |   -- log4j.properties
```

Similarly, I have another project whose structure is:

```
ProjB.ear
 |-- ProjB.war
 |-- Util.war
 |   |-- WEB-INF
 |   |   |-- classes
 |   |   |   -- log4j.properties
```

Util.war is a common project (except log4j.properties) for both ProjA and ProjB.

Below is how I have specified the dependency of Util.war in both ProjA and ProjB:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
```

Now the question is: As I have different versions of log4j.properties file for each project, how can I configure Maven to add ProjA specific file while packaging ProjA and use the other version when packaging ProjB?

Please let me know if you don't understand the jumbled scenario :).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i think you could remove your log4j.properties out of the Util.war because it is application depended. instead you could use the ProjA.ear/APP-INF/classes and ProjB/APP-INF/classes folder for this.

see [What difference between app-inf and web-inf folders in JavaEE applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191794/what-difference-between-app-inf-and-web-inf-folders-in-javaee-applications)

Your Application Server is adding this folder automatically to the Class-Path. But be aware of parent first / child first class loading

see [Java EE and Java SE classloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210389/java-ee-and-java-se-classloading/18210710#18210710)

> However, In Java EE, a classloader first tries to load the class itself and then delegate the classloading of that class to its parent classloader.

This statement is depending on your Application Server.